# Blazor @bind-Value on input sets the values with single quotes

Tags: .net, blazor

I have bind my inputs to a model in my page and when I press the submit button to see the values at the object they are surrounded with single quotes for example:

**Email**: 'test@test.com' , **Password**: '123'

Here is a code sample. Am I doing something wrong?

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp2.Classes;

<PageTitle>Test Page</PageTitle>

<input @bind-value="loginModel.Email" type="text"/>
<input @bind-value="loginModel.Password" type="password" />
<button @onclick="ExecuteLogin">Submit</button>

@code {
    private LoginModel loginModel;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        loginModel = new LoginModel();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void ExecuteLogin()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be all in order, this has to do with the way you display or use the values:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Test Page</PageTitle>

<input @bind-value="loginModel.Email" type="text"/>
<input @bind-value="loginModel.Password" type="password" />
<button @onclick="ExecuteLogin">Submit</button>

<div>
"@loginModel.Email"
"@loginModel.Password"
</div>
@code {

    class LoginModel
    {
        public string Email = "";
        public string Password = "";
    }
    private LoginModel loginModel;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        loginModel = new LoginModel();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void ExecuteLogin()
    {

    }
}
```

See, there are no extra 's:
https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cwvwbsvH012HWMth43

Comment: I need to pass the LoginModel object to a service but if you inspect the object the values are surrounded with single quotes.

Comment: I inspected, and they are not. They are strings. Are you using VS debugger?

Comment: this is really weird.... I see them with single quotes while debugging.

Comment: Debugger adds these to denote that they are string? There are no \' contained in the strings themselves...